# Count continuously repeated value in a column per id in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with historical data, and I want to store the data that had been the same the LAST 20 times per ID

So I have a table like this, order with date DESC: ( I want to add somehow this COUNT column)

```
id  flight_code src_terminal    departure_at      COUNT
0   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-13          0
1   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-13          1
2   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-10          2
3   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-09          3
4   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-08          4
5   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-08          5
6   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-07          6
7   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-07          7
8   YW-MAD-BOD      5           2019-11-06          0
9   YW-MAD-BOD      4           2019-11-05          0
44  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-13          0
45  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-12          2
46  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-11          3
47  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-10          4
48  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-10          5
49  XQ-ADB-AYT      D           2019-11-09          6
```

So I want to go row by row, checking if the flight_code is = to the previous row flight_code, if yes, check if the src_terminal is = to the previous src_terminal and sum +1

And later when I have this column, I want t  filter then ones that had more than 20 times the same terminal

I tried this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
for i in range(2,len(df)):
  x=0
  count=[]
  while (df.flight_code.loc[i] == df.flight_code.loc[i-1]) & (df.src_terminal.loc[i] == df.src_terminal.loc[i-1]):
    x=x+1
    count.append[x]
    if (df.flight_code.loc[i] != df.flight_code.loc[i-1]):
      break
```

How may I approach this to get only a list of flight codes were the src_terminal been the same from the first date (the most recent) to more than 20? Here is a graphic example of the ones I need to keep:
[image: graphic example]

Comment: I guess you have an error on your output 4s != 4, but the count is 8, otherwise this could be done using groupby + cumcount.

Comment: No, thats correct, is the type of cases I want to filter out.

Comment: You said if src_terminal == previous src_terminal, 4s is not equal to 4.

Comment: I think the lat 6 rows should count from 0-5, not 1-6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
groups=df[['flight_code','src_terminal']].ne(df[['flight_code','src_terminal']].shift()).cumsum().sum(axis=1)
df['COUNT']=df.groupby(groups).cumcount()
print(df)

    id flight_code src_terminal departure_at  COUNT
0    0  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-13      0
1    1  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-13      1
2    2  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-10      2
3    3  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-09      3
4    4  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-08      4
5    5  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-08      5
6    6  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-07      6
7    7  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-07      7
8    8  YW-MAD-BOD            5   2019-11-06      0
9    9  YW-MAD-BOD            4   2019-11-05      0
10  44  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-13      0
11  45  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-12      1
12  46  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-11      2
13  47  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-10      3
14  48  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-10      4
15  49  XQ-ADB-AYT            D   2019-11-09      5
```

---

**Detail of groups**

```
print(groups)
0     2
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     4
10    6
11    6
12    6
13    6
14    6
15    6
dtype: int64
```